# Image doesn't download when I want to use a mobile device

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mobile

I have a web site and I want to be able to download file in mobile devices.
I don´t have problem when I access to my web page and download an image from pc's browser but if I want to do from mobile device the image doesn't download, mobile's browser opens other page with image.

This is my code for this section:

```
@Override
    public void download(String nameImage, HttpServletResponse response) {
        ImageEntity image = imageRepository.findByName(nameImage);
        response.setContentType("image/" + image.getExtension());
        File localFile = new File(pathManager.getPathCompleteOfImageUpload()+nameImage);
        try {
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(localFile);
            org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
            response.flushBuffer();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

and Header is

```
private void setHeader(HttpServletResponse response, String name) {
        String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
        String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", name);
        response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);
    }
```

Can you help me?

Thanks you so much!